# Casio fx-83GB PLUS, how to perform x mod y?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

How can I perform

x mod y (e.g. 89^3 mod 3127)

on this calculator?

I got Cryptography exam tomorrow and I can't figure out how to do the mod part on the calc that I have..

This is the encrypting part of RSA algorithm.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt your calculator has a modulus function. Here's a decent algorithm that works:

1. Compute 89^3 = 704 969. Write this down or store the result somewhere.
2. Now reduce modulo n. To do this,  compute result / modulus and ignore the decimal, e.g. 704 969 / 3127 ≈ 225.
3. Multiply that number by the modulus and subtract it from the original result, e.g. 704 969 - 225*3127 = 1394.

If the original exponentiation is so large that it overflows your calculator, you can compute a smaller exponent and do the above reduction modulo n multiple times. For example, if you're asking to compute 89^10, you can instead compute 89^5, reduce that modulo n, square that result to get 89^10, and reduce the squared value modulo n as well.

A key point is that at pretty much any point in the computation process, you can reduce the value modulo n and still arrive at the same figure. Your professor may throw a curveball at you like this - or they may not. Still, better to be prepared.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question and also giving an alternative to achieve the calculation! I doubt the professor will give anything really big as he knows almost no one, who takes the module, understands how RSA really works.